# Drawing VectorDrawable at Different Sizes

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a simple VectorDrawable in an app. It comes from the android SDK and looks like so:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,17.27L18.18,21l-1.64,-7.03L22,9.24l-7.19,-0.61L12,2 9.19,8.63 2,9.24l5.46,4.73L5.82,21z"/>
</vector>
```

I want to draw it into a 400x400 bitmap such that it scales to fill the bitmap. Currently, when I draw it, it shows up only at 24x24. Here's the code:

```
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    VectorDrawable drawable = (VectorDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.testvector, null);
//  drawable.mutate();

    int width = 400
    int height = 400;
    Bitmap mutableImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            metrics, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableImage);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: What do you have in `metrics`? What you want works for me when I leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

I checked only on VectorDrawableCompat, let me know if it will work for you.

Works for me as long as I didn't rotate view that contains VectorDrawableCompat.

```
ImageView view;
...
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 400;
layoutParams.height = 400;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
Drawable drawable = view.getDrawable().mutate();//Vector
view.setImageDrawable(drawable);// <- that's a hack
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = container.getDrawingCache();
```